# How to setup sub channels on web socket

Tags: playframework, websocket, netty

I am using play20

I have web sockets that use Netty 3.5.0  and i need to find way to use sub channels on each socket.

it is possible and how ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a different prefix for messages on each of the channels. For example, if you want to send "hello" on channel 1, you send "1hello" instead. Then you have an web socket handler that parses these messages and dispatches them to other actors or iteratees according to the prefix.

Comment: Thanks ,

from server side i have one out channel how can i send  2 messages  to client at the same time with blocking one of the message.

something like Multiplexing the web socket

Comment: If you have one channel to one client, the messages will arrive at the client sequentially, no matter what you do. The trick then is to process the messages at the client in an asynchronous manner. Maybe you can use web workers for that, but it really depends on what the client is doing with those messages.